# Strategy to avoid duplicate GCM notifications in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I would like notify the user of the app when a certain criteria has been met, eg the auction price has reached a certain point or the price of a certain TV has fallen below a threshold set by the user.

Whenever the app registers for notifications, a registration token from google is returned. However registration tokens are not permanent and may change, leading to multiple tokens and duplication notifications.

**Android approach**

Canonical IDs are returned when as a response to a send (or even dry_run) in the following form -  "... success":7,
   "failure":0,
   "canonical_ids":2,
   "results":  ....    [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) which can then be used to extract the canonical ID.

For iOS GCM notification canonical IDs are not returned.

**Alternative approach (key-value)**
An alternative approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805143/canonical-ids-for-ios-notifications-over-gcm) is to use a store gcm registration tokens together with a key. Then if gcm registration token changes you can find the old token based on the key.

[Suggested object for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805143/canonical-ids-for-ios-notifications-over-gcm#comment51600039_31816759) was apns device token, however the device token is also subject to change - “Also note that the delegate method may be called any time the device token changes”.  [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

I looked at using [UIDevice identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) as a possible key, but this changes across uninstall/install cycle.

**Is the a best practice?**
Is there recommended way to avoid duplication notifications from not being able to track registration tokens to unique devices? Canonical ID for iOS, a unique key for the key-value approach?

**Proposed Solution (feedback welcome)**

On the server, include the registration token (destination/to field) as part of the notification payload. On the client side (iOS app), extract the registration id from the notification payload. On the client keep track of what the registration id received from payloads and send back to the the server the fact that you are receiving notifications with multiple registration token. The server can then expire the older registration tokens, and/or the client can even send which registration token that it knows (stored in sharedpreferences from last registration) to be current

Comment: Thanks for sharing this vital information. Is there any question you want to raise with the current instant messaging mechanism on Android or iOS platforms?

Comment: @AniV, my questions are at the end. Is there a best practice for handling duplication notifications? If there isnt, is my proposed solution ok?